# Details on Marketing Cloud Permissions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions

Does anyone have any details or a link to a page that explains the granular permissions within Marketing Cloud?

The documentation is atrocious in this area. It looks clear in the documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_roles.htm&type=5) but then when you go in the backend of marketing cloud, there are so many permissions that are never mentioned in the documentation...ever. For instance, why's there a section on "Xpress" or "tmMessenger", I have no idea how any of these relate to Marketing Cloud users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is afaik no page containing explanation of all the specific permissions you can set up in custom roles. However, I have a list of the less commonly known ones, including the two you ask about:

1. SocialEngage - This is a portion of Social Studio
2. Marketo - This is no longer valid
3. DeveloperApp - This gives the ability to create custom Apps for use with Marketing Cloud
4. Social Pages - SocialPages is an app in the Marketing Cloud that allows you to create, schedule, and publish content for your Facebook Fan pages without navigating through Facebook Developer screens and building fan pages from scratch. SocialPages support ended on 12/31/2016 and is replaced by CloudPages.
5. Discover - Discover is a premium data and analytics tool used to create your own reports. Reports are generated instantly and can be rendered in various formats including a grid view, bar graph, pie chart, heat grid, and scatter. The reports can be saved and viewed by others or exported.
6. Data Factory Utility - Used with Audience Builder. The Data Factory Utility activity moves and transforms data from a source database to the target (Audience Builder) database for applications that run off of the target database.
7. Xpress - No longer valid
8. AdobeAnalytics - Integrated feature if you use Adobe for analytics tracking
9. tmMessenger - This is a feature specifically for Ticketmaster/LiveNation so you would never use this.
10. LEMI - No longer valid
11. Transactional Sending - Allows sending of Transactional emails
12. Email Send Wizard - Allows you to send emails from Marketing Cloud
13. 3Sixty - No longer valid

Comment: Wow this is helpful! Thanks so much Lukas!!!

Comment: @Lukas: Do you also have on your list what the "Mutual SSL" permission does? This puzzles me a bit because I recently got the feedback from someone on the Salesforce team that SFMC doesn't support mutual authentication. The context was a secure REST API integration.

Comment: To be honest - I don't have info on this permission. Expect this to be a legacy feature. And yes, confirming that indeed mutual authentication is not possible on SFMC